# Create bracket notation from array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings like this:

```js
const deepProperties = ['contactPerson', 'firstName']
```

How can access the property `contactPerson.firstName` (get and set) of an anonymous object having this string array at hand?

```js
const unknown = { contactPerson: { firstName: 'Jane' } }
```

I know I can do `unknown['contactPerson']['firstName']` to get the value and `unknown['contactPerson']['firstName'] = 'John'` to set a new value - but how do I get there from the array?

Comment: `deepProperties.reduce((p, c) => p[c], unknown);`, potentially with optional chaining, if there is a chance it doesn't exist.

Comment: Any reason not to use: `unknown[deepProperties[0]][deepProperties[1]]`?

Comment: @jarmod the number of strings in the array is dynamic.

Comment: Perhaps lodash get/set would work for you ([examples](https://www.penta-code.com/lodash-get-and-set/)). You'd have to join the property names, for example: `deepProperties.join(".")` to create the relevant hierarchical property path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get)/[set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set).

For example:

```
const get = require('lodash.get');
const set = require('lodash.set');

const deepProperties = ['contactPerson', 'firstName']
const unknown = { contactPerson: { firstName: 'Jane' } }

get(unknown, deepProperties.join("."))
// 'Jane'

set(unknown, deepProperties.join("."), "Mary")
// { contactPerson: { firstName: 'Mary' } }
```

Note that this would also work if the embedded properties included arrays, for example:

```
const props = ["users[1]", "name"];
const org = { users:[{name:"joe",age:21}, {name:"mary",age:29}] };

get(org, props.join("."));
// 'mary'
```